# How to install non-library file on app-lib directory

Tags: android, native

I am working on building an app that depends on a 3rd party shared library.
The library requires to have a data file on the same directory as the library installed in the device runtime. When I package my app with ant, I can include data non-library(^.so) file in the apk by adding a custom rule.
However, when the apk is actually installed on the device, the data file is not extracted but only library is. I see still in the apk file. The data file has the fixed name and it does not end with *.so.
Anyone has an idea how to have non-library file on the app-lib directory?

Im using adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk

Comment: Not sure what your 3rd party library does (or how/when it looks for the file), but one way to control where the file ends up, is by copying it there at runtime, the first time your app is launched. The `assets` or `res/raw` folders would then be a sensible way to bundle the file. Copying it into the right location should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/VLUP5ZDNx28/B28eQ_vUm6cJ)

---

Summary:

There is no way to have the Android System do this automatically on install. You can bundle it as a resource in your APK and then copy it yourself on the first run of your application.